# PDF doc text shows differently in IE / Firefox / Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, pdf-generation

I try to produce a PDF text file with Hebrew text.

I managed to produce a simple file. file is [here](http://www.nispahit.com/stack/problematic.pdf)

The file opens in Adobe Acrobat Reader perfectly, showing the string "אאא ווו תתת".
It opens perfectly also in IE.

The problem is other viewers show it badly:
Google Chrome / Google Docs show it without all "ו" occurances (that is, three letters "ו" disapear!)

Mozilla Firefox show it very badly, showing some letters many times and in odd places on the page...

What am I doing wrong??
What is wrong in the file?

[A link to the file is here](http://www.nispahit.com/stack/problematic.pdf)

I know this is a tough question.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong. I checked the file for syntax errors with Adobe Acrobat's Preflight functionality and it says all is fine. The problem you're experiencing is caused by the fact that Chrome uses Chrome PDF viewer by default and Firefox uses pdf.js. Both are unfinished versions of a PDF viewer. They don't have full support for ISO-32000-1 (the PDF standard). You can change this default so that Chrome and Firefox use the Adobe Reader plug-in, but usually you can't expect from an end user to know how to do that.

Comment: Did you code it by hand? Can't believe any API would produce *this*. If it's kind of exercise, have you examined COS-structure of any similar PDF, or read the Reference?

Comment: @Bruno, Thanks! it was a helpful comment. I still try to find out what went wrong with the reading of the file in the other viewers. Maybe I'll look into the pdf.js to try understand what's going on there...

Comment: @VadimR, I use the free PDFClown Java library. What did you mean by "*this*"? I don't have a similar file (my trial with Adobe Acrobat has finished - do you know how else can I create a similar file?). I did read some of the Reference (The relevant parts...)

Comment: Please disregard my "can't believe" and "have read the reference". I didn't expect text space operators allowed outside a text object, my fault. Other than very minor violations, syntax seems **OK**. But, it's still unusual for me to see Type0 `Encoding` and CIDFont `CID2GIDMap` anything other than `Identity` in not East Asian files, even for PDF with Hebrew text.

Comment: Look, though, I fixed your file. Original didn't work not only in browsers, but in MuPDF and FoxIt Reader, too. [Now](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqmzm0rexu5155f/problematic%2B%2B.pdf) it works. These viewers expect character code `0x0020` (and/or CID `0x0020`) to be `space` character -- looks like they don't even check if it can be something else -- like `vav` letter, in your original. I placed it as `0x0004`. Well, bug or not, if so many viewers won't show a file correctly, it doesn't seem a good idea, the way PDFClown encodes files.

Comment: @VadimR, Thank you so much! There is still a problem with fireFox and some viewers like PDF Architect, but this problem was the most common. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: H-mm, it looks like Firefox has its own issue - when character codes in encoding can be either 1 or 2 bytes. Hence problem with widths and using 'vav' for both `0x20` and `0x0020` in original. I'll make another fixed PDF and put it all together in an answer, later.

Comment: @VadimR, Your file works. But you changed only the CMap of ToUnicode, not the CMap of Encoding. To my understanding, this should influence text exporting (for example: copy&paste) but not the text shown. I tried to do exactly as you said, but got '÷' instead of 'vav'. When I copy&paste it, I get the 'vav'. [changed file here](http://www.nispahit.com/stack/stillProblematic.pdf). I now wonder, how is it that your file works? Did you change something else? Also, I changed with NP++ your file's value of 0x0020 in ToUnicode CMap to it's original value, and it still works! Do you understand why??

Comment: The file you created, after my notepad++ change (only change back the ToUnicode 0x0004) - which STRANGELY still works, is [here](http://www.nispahit.com/stack/strangeNotProblematic.pdf)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### A very short and simplified introduction

Fonts in PDF are *PDF objects* - `Font` dictionaries, containing numerous parameters and sub-dictionaries, necessary to select glyphs, show them and translate character codes to logical (Unicode) representation for content extraction. Fonts in layman terms -- as we see them as *.ttf or *.pfb files -- are called *font programs*, either embedded or external, and are referred to by one of sub-dictionaries of `Font` objects.

`Fonts` are divided into two groups:

- Simple fonts (Type1, Type3 or TrueType), in which glyphs are selected by single-byte character codes obtained from a string that is shown by the text-showing operators. The mapping from codes to glyphs is called the font’s *encoding*, it can be either built-in into font program or defined by `Font` object (by predefined name or explicitly) or, under special circumstances, constructed according to defined rules by viewer application.

The file in question doesn't contain simple fonts, and we won't discuss them any further -- but, note, over-simplistic description doesn't even start to reflect any of real-life complexity.

- Composite fonts (Type0), used to show text in which character codes can have variable length (up to 4 bytes), and which, therefore, isn't restricted to 256 code-points. *Type0* font always has one *descendant* which is a *font-like object* called `CIDFont`, and, similar to encoding for simple fonts, a `CMap` object, that maps character codes to character selectors, which, in PDF, are always `CIDs` -- integers up to 65536.

Now, character selector (`CID`) is not, in general,  directly used to select glyphs from font program. For `CIDFont` of `CIDFontType2` type, its dictionary contains `CIDToGIDMap` entry, that, obviously, maps `CID` to glyph identifiers. Those `GIDs` are, at last, used to select glyphs from embedded *font program* (which, for `CIDFontType2` font, is a *TrueType* font program (do not confuse with `Font` object of *TrueType* `Subtype`)).

`Font` object can have `ToUnicode` resource, that maps CIDs to Unicode values for indexing, searching and extraction. It's called `ToUnicode Cmap` (as it follows similar syntax), but it should not to be confused with `CMap` object, mentioned above.

In what I call a simple case (and, I think, sensible decision), `CMap` is predefined **Identity-H** name, `CIDToGIDMap` is a predefined **Identity** name, and, therefore, character codes extracted from a string (argument to text showing operator) are always 2-byte numbers that, effectively, directly select glyphs from embedded *TrueType* program. From my experience, it's most common scenario, and as it appears, that's the case, against which common software is tested.

But, it's not the case with file in question.

#### (The end of a short and simplified introduction)

In our file, text showing operator, effectively, gets this string:

```
0x000a 0x000a 0x000a 0x20 0x0020 0x0020 0x0020 0x20 0x0025 0x0025 0x0025
```

Of course there are no 'groups', they are here because I made them, based on `CMap` that contains 2 ranges:

```
<20> <20>
<0000> <19FF>
```

To make a long story short, if we look up character codes in `CMap` and get CIDs, then look up CIDs in `CIDToGIDMap` and get GIDs, then look up GIDs in embedded **David-Bold** font and get Unicode values, here's the table

```
Code        CID     GID     Unicode     Name

0x000a      10      180     05EA        tav
0x0020      32      159     05D5        vav
0x0025      37      154     05D0        alef
0x20        228     03      0020        space
```

Now we have enough information to speculate, what confuses viewer applications

---

In my first attempt, I suggested it's `32` code (and `CID`) that's used for non-space character (see comment above). This assumption was based on a case, several years ago, when (older version of) Acrobat didn't show character with `0x20` code, when it's at the end of a string -- assuming it to be `space`, when in fact, according to encoding vector (of a simple font), it was another character.

I changed this:

- `0x0020` to `0x0004` in content stream;
- bytes 08 and 09 in `CIDToGIDMap` to GID=159;
- value in `Widths` array of CID=4 to 'vav' width;
- `ToUnicode cmap` was adjusted accordingly.
- (+ later I tried to remove `<0020> 32` string from `CMAP` - not reflected in a file, linked in comment)

Well, it did help, but unfortunately, some of viewers still rejected to comply to specification.

---

Then I thought, that maybe variable character code width was the issue.

I returned to the original file and changed this:

- `0x20` to `0x00e4` in content stream;
- `<20> 228` to `<00e4> 228` in `CMAP`;
- `codespacerange` `<20> <20>` in `CMAP` deleted;
- `codespacerange` `<20> <20>` in `ToUnicode Cmap` deleted.

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5myq23zd2w4w1k5/problematic_fixed.pdf) file appears to open perfectly in all viewers, mentioned in original question and comments below. Miraculously, `0x0020` code and `32` `CID` do not interfere.

---

The conclusion, I think, can be this:

Given current state of affairs, PDF-creators are **NOT** advised to mix single and double byte codes in font encoding (`CMAP`).

Comment: No doubt - you are a PDF expert. I thank you **deeply** for your efforts on this great answer. It really made me understand.