# How are various glyphs encoded inside a PDF content stream?

Tags: c, pdf, encoding, utf-8, fonts

I am working on a program that outputs PDF documents. Given a sequence of UTF-8 encoded characters and the name of a font that shall be used to render it, I would like to show the appropriate glyphs that make the actual content of the document. I would like to be able to display national characters such as *č* or *ö*. It would be great to support ligatures like *ae* or *ffi*.

The problem is, I do not know how the actual glyphs to be shown are specified (inside a content stream, for example).

If I, for example, want to display the string "Hello World", I need not to worry about encoding, I simply write `(Hello World)Tj`. The PDF reader will then use the appropriate font to render this string.

But what if I wanted to show the string
**It is difficult to read the PDF specification all day. Prostě dočista nemožné!**
with the ligatures *ffi*, *fi* and *ea* and the Czech national symbols *ě*, *č* and *é* in a given font, how would I proceed?

I am trying to get through the PDF specification, but it is not easy.

- How do I find out the "code of the glyph" that corresponds to a given character or ligature?
- How is this code *encoded* within a PDF content stream?

Help is much appreciated.

---

**Edit:** I may have overestimated the problem. Counting the glyphs that are needed to display a "common European document", I cannot think of a way how this number could exceed 256. If my assumptions are correct, I can remap the encoding of the font completely. This should be sufficient to cover all common symbols of the latin alphabet, numbers, punctuation, common symbols like `(` and `[` and still I would have plenty of room for national symbols, ligatures and other elements of high-quality typography. (I can implement a priority queue to select the most used ligatures if the total number of glyphs shall exceed 256.)

That being said, I do not think I need to use the CID-keyed fonts.

Still I wander how do I map UTF-8 encoded characters onto glyphs of an arbitrary font. I have the AFM of the font available. For the *DejaVu* font, for example, character information go like this:

```
C 63 ; WX 536 ; N question ; B 67 -15 488 743 ;
C 64 ; WX 1000 ; N at ; B 65 -174 930 705 ;
C 65 ; WX 722 ; N A ; B -6 0 732 730 ;
```

But after the 256<sup>th</sup> character is mapped, the codes are `-1`:

```
C 255 ; WX 564 ; N ydieresis ; B -3 -223 563 767 ;
C -1 ; WX 722 ; N Amacron ; B -6 0 732 899 ;
C -1 ; WX 596 ; N amacron ; B 49 -15 568 746 ;
```

For example, if I had the sequence `11100010 10000010 10101100` (Euro sign) in my input, how would I know what glyph name it corresponds to so that I can map it in the `/Encoding` dictionary?

Comment: PDF is old, it got started before Unicode.  It is infected with the [code page virus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Encodings) as a result.  Immunization is already provided by the many existing libraries that can read them, very little point in re-inventing one.

Comment: However I have to, it is a school project. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Talk to your teacher, you've misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: Judging from your reaction, it seems I won't sleep well tonight. I haven't. The idea behind the program is simple: take plain text, output PDF. *But*, do support UTF-8 input. From the Wikipedia article section you've sent a link to, it seems I cannot use more than 256 characters within a single document, but I know this must be possible (Chinese symbols are thousands and supported). How does this work? I understand how a simple encoding table works inside the PDF, but how do I encode more than 256 characters? Once again, thanks.

Comment: BTW, re: "difficult to read the PDF specification". I find that document published by Adobe ([pdf](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)) is much easier to read than [ISO version](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), both in typesetting and subtle specific language. It may be just what I'm used to, but give it a try.

Comment: @VadimR Even if I had different opinion on the easy of reading of this, it is great to have two sources to rely upon. Thanks! Never knew there was another version.

Comment: Besides plinth's great answer, you may also be interested in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999809/pdf-doc-text-shows-differently-in-ie-firefox-chrome/20022119#20022119) to another question. Note "simple case" I mention there - double-byte codes from content stream are effectively glyph IDs from font program. I think it's easier than inventing encoding, manually, for Type1 font. All structures for Type0 and descendants may look frightening but they aren't, really.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Encoding varies based on the font type.  Typically, there is a font resource that is defined as the current font and within that font dictionary is a reference to a base font and a means of describing the encoding (via the `/Encoding` key).  If that key doesn't exist, the encoding will be "standard", but you can use other simple encodings such as `/MacRoman` and `/WinAnsi` for the value of the encoding, or you can specify a standard encoding and an encoding delta to show the differences.

Easy so far - as long as you're working with 8-bit characters.  For many early apps, they would create a couple different fonts, one with say Roman encoding and another that maps roman characters to unavailable characters.  In order to do that, your encoding delta would include references to the ligatures and other typically non-encoded symbols.  This works great for Type 1 fonts, but is specifically contraindicated by the spec in the section on TrueType Fonts:

> A nonsymbolic font should specify MacRomanEncoding or WinAnsiEncoding as the value of its Encoding entry, with no Differences array

This is vastly different when you want to use, say, Unicode.  In which case you would be using a CID font (a font based on character IDs).  In that case there is a procedure referenced by the font which is used to map from a character encoding in your string to a character ID in your font (and vice versa).  I would strongly recommend that you read and fully understand section 9.7 in the PDF specification on Composite Fonts, which describes everything you need in order to encode UTF16BE into strings to get them to render properly in PDF.  It is decidedly non-trivial in that there are a lot of details that if missed will result in a blank rendered page in Acrobat.

As a software engineer who professionally writes code that produces and consumes PDF, let me state that when I get tasked with having to put in special cases in my code to deal with non-spec compliant PDF, a little piece of me dies inside.  Please, please, don't even think of releasing any documents you produce into the wild until they pass Preflight at the least.  This is not the same as "Acrobat renders it so it must be OK."  Let me give you an example - I've seen a number of files in the wild that include fonts that are missing the key elements of the FontDescriptor dictionary, including `/Ascent`, `/Descent`, `/CapHeight`, etc.  These render in Acrobat, but are in violation of the spec since each of those is required.  I know how Acrobat handles that - it comes with an enormous database of font metrics and looks up the value if it can't find it in the file (heck, it might even ignore the metrics in the file).  I don't have that luxury, so I have to do a number of (potentially expensive/invalid) stop gap measures.

You might want to consider using a library to do this work for you - maybe iText which has a decent enough licensing scheme for education because, I get it, you're a student.  There are some C based libraries too.  Maybe you can figure a way to make GhostScript do your bidding.

If you are unwilling or unable to follow my advice with regards to cleaving to the specification or to use a library which ostensibly does so, please do me the favor of at least filling out the `/Creator` and `/Producer` strings in the Document Information Dictionary referenced by the trailer (see sections 14.3.3 and section 7.5.5).  That way, when I have to parse/consume/manipulate your documents, I will have a way to directly cast aspersions on your parentage.

Let's go top down and start with the page object - I'm using output from my own library and am stripping out what I *think* you don't need:

```
1 0 obj << 
    /Type /Page 
    /Parent 18 0 R 
    /Resources << 
       /Font << 
          /U0 13 0 R 
          >>
       /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]
       >>   
    /MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
    /Contents 19 0 R    
    /Dur -1 
    >>
 endobj
```

U0 is a reference to a font that will be used for unicode text.

The content stream is intended to print the following text: `Greek: Γειά σου κόσμος`.

```
BT /U0 24 Tf 72 670 Td 
(\000G\000r\000e\000e\000k\000:\000 \003\223\003\265\003\271\003\254\000 \003\303\003\277\003\305\000 \003\272\003\314\003\303\003\274\003\277\003\302) 
Tj ET
```

The font dictionary referenced looks like this:

```
13 0 obj << 
    /BaseFont /DejaVuSansCondensed 
    /DescendantFonts [ 4 0 R  ]
    /ToUnicode 14 0 R 
    /Type /Font 
    /Subtype /Type0 
    /Encoding /Identity-H 
>>
endobj
```

Which has the `/ToUnicode` entry points to a stream containing the following PostScript code:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 12 dict begin begincmap /CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def /CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def /CMapType 2 def 1 begincodespacerange <0000> <FFFF> endcodespacerange 1 beginbfrange <0000> <FFFF> <0000> endbfrange endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end
```

which is defined by the [CID font specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5014.CIDFont_Spec.pdf).

and the DescendantFonts array points to this object:

```
4 0 obj << 
    /Subtype /CIDFontType2 
    /Type /Font 
    /BaseFont /DejaVuSansCondensed 
    /CIDSystemInfo 7 0 R 
    /FontDescriptor 8 0 R 
    /DW 1000 
    /W 9 0 R 
    /CIDToGIDMap 10 0 R 
>>
```

The CIDToGIDMap is a compressed stream with the actual map, the CIDSystemInfo is `<</Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (USC) /Supplement 0>>` (it's a reference because I share it among all unicode fonts that I output.  The FontDescriptor is a straight forward boiler plate, and the W array is derived from the font metrics.

With all this detail, are you understanding why I don't say lightly, "walk away before you pollute my environment any furhter"?

I'm really beginning to question the nature of the this assignment.  Writing a simple PDF is one thing, but writing code that can handle full unicode in any arbitrary OpenType/TrueType font requires you to understand the CID spec *and* the TrueType spec (hint: I have a full TrueType parser that can extract all the metrics for any glyph in a font so that I can output the /W array).

If, however, you are required to only output to Type 1 fonts, well my friend, your life got a whole lot easier, because you would take your entire UTF8 stream, read it as unicode and for every unique character that comes in, you build a map from a unicode character to a glyph name and an internal character number by using [this table](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/opentype/aglfn13.txt).  The internal character number essentially the unique index of the character that came in mod.  So for example, if you have less than 257 unique characters on the page, you will have exactly one font that is encoded to map to the characters in the order that the arrived.  If you had "abcba" for input, the output string in pdf would be `(\000\001\002\001\000)` and would map to a font with an encoding dictionary with a differences array that would be `[0/a/b/c]`.  If you have *n* unique characters where *n* > 256, you're going to have (*n* / 256) + 1 fonts, each with encodings.

If your teacher/professor wants anything but Type 1 fonts in a short period of time, s/he has unrealistic expectations for the students and/or low expectations for the quality of output.  You should ask whether your are required to handle CID fonts and if you are, then your professor is at the very least a sadist.  It took me, a seasoned professional, about 4 days to write a TrueType parser for extracting widths.  I had the advantage of (1) using a managed language (C#) which cut down on concerns that will be biting your ass in C and was also able to use reflection to automate parsing and (2) when I don't have interruptions, I write solid code about 10-20 times faster than a typical student, so my 32 hours would translate into 320 student hours, more or less (then again, my code has different constraints than yours - it has to consume any crap font it gets gracefully), so let's call it 200 or less if you're allowed to steal something like [stb](http://nothings.org/stb/).  That's just for getting one particular element in the font descriptor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It is surprising how many people ask me to do them various favors, especially not to create any PDF documents by myself! :) Actually, I really want this to be done the right way. Lack of free PDF validation tools is what makes it hard. I cannot use a library, that is forbidden directly. I will read section 9.7 of the Adobe PDF Reference as you advice. Would you mind if I asked from time to time as I pass through it?

Comment: At this point, I think it would be out of the scope of your question (while I wrote this, I wasn't aware that this was homework).  The best I can offer is that you should look at simple output, which I've edited into my answer and see if you can reproduce it.

Comment: I have updated my question. From your point of view, is it a bad practice to completely remap the font's encoding and presumably break ASCII compatibility in many cases?

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation. I am sure 256 characters per document will be enough. When I came with the idea of writing this, my professor asked me what font formats I want to support. I replied: "I would stick with Type 1 for this time." And he smiled. When I said I will look into OpenType if I got the time left, he smiled again. Now I know why!

Comment: @David: you are fortunate to have a teacher that understands this stuff himself!

Comment: I’m developing a tool that generates PDF. (As a toy project for learning.) What is "Preflight"? I’m having a hard time finding it. When searching for a "validator" or "conformance checker" I find lots of things about PDF/A, which I don’t really care about.

Comment: Preflight is a tool built into Adobe Acrobat (not the Reader, so not free), which can run a number of different types of validations on a PDF document, including syntax and spec compliance.

Comment: You got to write that parser in C? Luxury! I've had to write the TTF font parser (and sub setting) as well as the PDF generation in ABAP. I implemented the second option, creating sub-fonts. It was easier, but I came here for an answer on `GSUB` and ligature handling like fi and AE (more the Arabic RTL variants actually).