# Extract text from pdf using itextsharp returns empty string

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a [pdf file](https://smlouvy.gov.cz/smlouva/soubor/5376672/Smlouva%20Z%C5%A0%20Komensk%C3%A9ho%2066%20NJ%20-%20pron%C3%A1jem%20u%C4%8Debny.pdf). The text can be extracted in Edge browser or in adobe reader after installing some fonts. Please let me know how to extract the text with itextsharp (latest version 5.x). I use this commands. Empty text is returning. But the file has 8 pages with text.

```
  var reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
  var pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
  for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
  {
    var t = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
    text += t;
  }
```

Comment: Are you really sure that you can extract the text with any other programm at all?

Comment: *itextsharp (latest version 5.x)* -> that is not correct. The latest version is iText 7.1.0, released this month. The name iTextSharp is no longer used, the name is iText for .NET.

Comment: There is text in there (with "fully transparent" as color) but if you change the text color to something else, you will see that this text is upside down. The character recognition software did what it could but that's not much. The first line reads something like "SM「On^V O NVで関n dHOS⊥OHu". (So this is not a programming problem.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem lies in the specific document that has been used, and not in the programming code.

Comment: @usr2564301 *"So this is not a programming problem."* - this might be considered a combined problem: The document indeed can not be salvaged without another OCR session. But there also is a programming problem because iText 5 does not correctly return the weird "recognized" text. I doubt, though, that it will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

#### The PDF

The PDF at first glance appears to be OCR'ed by an OCR program that did not realize that the pages are rotated by 180°.

For example, the OCR program on the second page started in what a PDF viewer displays as bottom left corner:

[image: screenshot bottom left corner page 2]

and here recognized

```
epnq eoⅢ9時u ez `9P...
押印S ’句OP JuP9A...
eA I臥O9叩Od n^Z小no...
```

This is not that bad, e.g. `epnq eoⅢ...` is not really unlike the `...mce bude` rotated by 180°.

The OCR software appears to have a certain affinity to CJK glyphs; this impression is reinforced by the fact that the it uses fonts with an Adobe-Japan1-2 ROS and a 90ms-RKSJ-H encoding.

#### Text extraction

All the information above considered, though, I have some doubt that

> The text can be extracted in Edge browser or in adobe reader after installing some fonts.

At least I doubt that anything similar to the actual text can be extracted, no matter how many fonts are installed. On the other hand both Adobe Reader and Edge out-of-the-box here extract the weird text recognized from the rotated letters.

#### iText

My observation with iText differs, while the OP reports that

> Empty text is returning

I get a lot of CJK glyphs (I have added the Asian jar, though, which might make a difference). Unfortunately, though, not those found by inspection of the PDF.

As far as I remember, though, text extraction by Encoding + ROS has never been in focus during iText development up to version 5.5.x (inclusive), in particular the mixed single-byte/double-byte encoding of 90ms-RKSJ-H might not be supported.

Comment: I just see that @usr2564301 reported in a comment about the up-side-down OCR'ing while I wrote my answer.

Comment: It's strange that you don't get the same characters – there *appears* to be nothing special mentioned in the encoding. I'll check the file again with some other tool. It indeed suggests a problem with iText. (But it seems unrelated to OPs problem. I am also quite sure this goes over OPs head.)

Comment: Well, it's a mixed multi-byte encoding; numerous PDF processors have been known to not handle such encodings well, cf. for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20022119/1729265).

Comment: (You're right about that encoding being a problem. Turns out my own tool doesn't recognize it either.)